# Putting 2 canvas shapes right next to each other with no gap?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm working in HTML Canvas with a hexagonal board. For the purpose of my application, each hexagon has a fill color, a black border, and a colored border (to signify who owns that particular hex).  When you select a hexagon, the fill turns light blue and your neighboring enemy hexagons fill turns red.

I'm finding it impossible to perfectly line up the colored border inside of the black boarder, without any sort of pixel gap.  Below is a close up picture. You can see at the very edges of the hightlighted hexagons, the fill color bleeds in between the colored border and the black border a little bit.

[image: pixel overlap]

Do you think this is a function of how I'm calculating the pixel locations for each hexagon, or is it just not possible to line up an angled shape to another angled shape because pixels are squares?

Below is the code that I use for creating a given hexagon (black border) and then putting the colored border inside of it.

```
//Main Hex
var numberOfSides = 6,
size = this.radius,
Xcenter = x0 + (this.width / 2),
Ycenter = y0 + (this.height / 2);
this.context.beginPath();
this.context.lineWidth = 1;
this.context.moveTo (Xcenter +  size * Math.cos(0), Ycenter +  size *  Math.sin(0));          
for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfSides;i += 1) {
    this.context.lineTo (Xcenter + size * Math.cos(i * 2 * Math.PI / numberOfSides), Ycenter + size * Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI / numberOfSides));
}
if (fillColor && highlight == false) {
    this.context.fillStyle = fillColor;
}
if (highlight == true){
    this.context.fillStyle = highlightColor;
    this.context.globalAlpha=0.65;
}
this.context.fill();
this.context.closePath();
this.context.stroke();

//Inside Colored Hex
var numberOfSides = 6,
size = this.radius-4.75,
Xcenter = x0 + (this.width / 2),
Ycenter = y0 + (this.height / 2);
this.context.strokeStyle = map.data[tile.row][tile.column].color;
this.context.beginPath();
this.context.lineWidth = 6;
this.context.moveTo (Xcenter +  size * Math.cos(0), Ycenter +  size *  Math.sin(0));          
for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfSides;i += 1) {
    this.context.lineTo (Xcenter + size * Math.cos(i * 2 * Math.PI / numberOfSides), Ycenter + size * Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI / numberOfSides));
}
this.context.closePath();
this.context.stroke();
```

The code for each is nearly identical, except the size and strokeStyle. Any thoughts? Any workarounds?

Comment: You're kind-of-right about the effect being caused by square pixels. What you're noticing is called anti-aliasing.  Drawing a diagonal line with square pixels causes a jagged stair-step effect. The browser attempts to visually reduce these "jaggies" by adding blended pixels along the jagged edge (those added pixels are the bleeding you're seeing). You can't turn Canvas's anti-aliasing off so the only workaround is to create your hexagon field pixel-by-pixel so the browser won't apply anti-aliasing (resulting in poor performance).

Comment: Hmm.  Without realizing it, I may have a solution.  If I made the fillStyle of the outer black hexagon the same color as the colored boarder hexagon, then make the fillStyle of the colored boarder hexagon equal to the green color on the map (which is a background), then the "bleeding" would just be seen as the colored boarder... which would eliminate this anti-aliasing. Right?   I'll try it out and report back.

Comment: In this case the bleeding is most likely due to rounding "errors" in the position values as they are all fractional. Try to shift the whole context 0.5 pixel (with translate, and globally once) then round all position values to closest integer value. If you set up a fiddle we can experiment a little with what rounding strategy works best here.